# Android getview() returns wrong position for a particular arraylist

Tags: android

```
 class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
String[] title,type;
 Context context;
 int page=1;
 int appno=0;
 private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
 ArrayList<String> latestTitle=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> latestLink=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> latestImg=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> latestStar=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> p=new ArrayList<String>();
 ImageLoader imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();
 DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true)
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10))

    .build();
public AppAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> latestImg,
        ArrayList<String> latestLink, ArrayList<String> latestStar,
        ArrayList<String> latestTitle, ArrayList<String> p) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    this.latestImg=latestImg;
    this.latestLink=latestLink;
    this.latestStar=latestStar;
    this.latestTitle=latestTitle;
    this.p=p;

}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return latestTitle.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return latestTitle.get(arg0);
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row=arg1;
    //LinearLayout seemore = null;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    //ImageLoaderConfiguration config = null;

    if(row==null)
    {
     holder=new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.applist, arg2, false);
    holder.title=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.para=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    holder.star1=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.singleStar);

    holder.star2=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.twoStar);
    holder.star3=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.threeStar);
    holder.star4=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.fourStar);
    holder.star5=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.fiveStar);



    holder.img=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag(); 
    }holder.position=arg0;
     holder.title.setText((arg0+1)+". "+latestTitle.get(arg0));
     holder.star1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.star2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.star3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.star4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.star5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        str=latestStar.get(arg0);
        Log.e("star"+arg0,latestStar.get(arg0));
        if(str.equals("width:20%;"))
        {
            holder.star1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             //Log.e("star"+1,str);
        }else if(str.equals("width:40%;"))
        {
            holder.star2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Log.e("star"+2,str);
        }else if(str.equals("width:60%;"))
        {
            holder.star3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Log.e("star"+3,str);
        }else if(str.equals("width:80%;"))
        {
            holder.star4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Log.e("star"+4,str);
        }else if(str.equals("width:100%;"))
        {
            holder.star5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Log.e("star"+5,str);
        }
     holder.para.setText(p.get(arg0));
    imageLoader.displayImage(latestImg.get(arg0), holder.img, options);
   if(arg0==latestTitle.size()-1)
   {page++;

   }
    return row;
}

}
private class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

     final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}



class ViewHolder
{   int position;
    ImageView img;
    LinearLayout star1,star2,star3,star4,star5;
    //LinearLayout seemore;
    TextView title,para;

}
```

this is my code,here arg0 is right for each arraylist but not for latestStar ,for latestStar Arraylist arg0 values are 1,3,4 and repeats again and again on scrolling.i have tried arrayadapter too but the result is same